# Required Field Validator in Ajax Accordion Pane is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

We using Ajax Accordion pane. We dynamically binding ajax accordion from data set. So we not sure how much pane wil be bind.

Now we added few textbox and 1 button in each accordion pane which is mandotory so we used required field validator.

The problem is when i click buton in first pane textbox in first pane showing "It is required" which is fine but even if i typed textbox in first pane. I am not able to save since textbox in remaining pane showing "It is required". Please guide me.

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="accRcvDetails" runat="server" SelectedIndex="-1" ContentCssClass="accordion-content" RequireOpenedPane="false" HeaderCssClass="accordion-header" 
                                     HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionSelected" OnItemCommand="accRcvDetails_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="accRcvDetails_ItemDataBound">

                                     <HeaderTemplate>
     </HeaderTemplate>
                                     <ContentTemplate>
    <td class="searchlabel">
                                                         <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server" Text="Notes:"></asp:Label>
                                                     </td>
                                                     <td class="searchtext" colspan="3">
                                                         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNotes" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="35px" />
                                                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtNotes" Text="Note Field is Required" runat="server" />
                                                     </td>
                                                     <td>
     <td style="text-align: right" colspan="8">
                                                         <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="searchbutton Accbtnsave" runat="server" CommandName="Save" Text="Save" />
                                                     </td>
 </ContentTemplate>


                                 </cc1:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention ValidationGroup for every textbox and button, as you are binding the accordion at runtime, so need to bind ValidationGroup at runtime with some property that has unique/different value for every accordian. Lets say you are binding accordion with rows of Groups, you can mention groupId in ValidationGroup then. Your updated code must looks alike:

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtNotes" Text="Note Field is Required" runat="server" ValidationGroup='<%# Eval("GroupId") %>'/>

 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="searchbutton Accbtnsave" runat="server" CommandName="Save" Text="Save" ValidationGroup='<%# Eval("GroupId") %>'/>
```

This way each accordion has its own ValidationGroup and clicking on button will not fire the validators in other accordions